# vue js removing duplicate values from filtered array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I want to  remove the duplicate datas from v-for loop in vue js. I have some clients in an array and some categories in another array. I am filtering the categories based on clientId's but it's showing the duplicate values also-

**Please select any client from the below snippet.**

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      clientId: 0,
      clients: [{
          "id": 1,
          "clientName": "Rafael Ellison"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "clientName": "Tad Beasley"
        },
        
      ],
      categories: [{
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type  1"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type  1"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 2"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 2"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 2,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 2"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 3"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 3"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 2,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 3"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "In veritatis anim al"
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPurchase() {
      return this.categories.filter(
        (client) => client.clientId == this.clientId
      );
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div>
    <div>
      <label>Under Client</label>
      <select v-model="clientId">
        <option value="" selected>select clients</option>
        <option v-for="client in clients" :key="client.id" :value="client.id">{{client.clientName}}</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="purchaseCategoryId">Purchase Type</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <select multiple>
          <option value="" selected>select purchase Type</option>
          <option v-for="purchase in filteredPurchase" :key="purchase.id" :value="purchase.purchaseType">{{purchase.purchaseType}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

there are many purchase type with the same name with differentt clientId. I want to delete the duplicate values from the purchase Types.

Comment: Do you want to delete duplicate purchase types per client?

Answer (score 1):

You can create computed property and remove duplicates:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      clientId: 0,
      clients: [{"id": 1, "clientName": "Rafael Ellison"},
        {"id": 2, "clientName": "Tad Beasley"}, 
      ],
      categories: [{"clientId": 1, "purchaseType": "Purchase Type  1"},
        {"clientId": 1, "purchaseType": "Purchase Type  1"},
        {"clientId": 1, "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 2"},
        {"clientId": 1, "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 2"},
        {"clientId": 2, "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 2"},
        {"clientId": 1, "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 3"},
        {"clientId": 1, "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 3"},
        {"clientId": 2, "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 3"},
        {"clientId": 1, "purchaseType": "In veritatis anim al"}
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    unique() {
      return [...new Map(this.categories.map(v => [JSON.stringify(v), v])).values()]
    },
    filteredPurchase() {
      return this.unique.filter(
        (client) => client.clientId == this.clientId
      );
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div>
    <div>
      <label>Under Client</label>
      <select v-model="clientId">
        <option value="" selected>select clients</option>
        <option v-for="client in clients" :key="client.id" :value="client.id">{{client.clientName}}</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="purchaseCategoryId">Purchase Type</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <select multiple>
          <option value="" selected>select purchase Type</option>
          <option v-for="purchase in filteredPurchase" :key="purchase.id" :value="purchase.purchaseType">{{purchase.purchaseType}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a JS-related issue.

*You can use the `Set constructor` which let us create sets, which are data structures that don’t have duplicate items.*

Here I fixed it in this way-

1. I used the [Set operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with `JSON.stringify` to create a set of stringified objects.
2. Convert the set back to the array using the `spread(...)` operator
3. Convert the array of strings back to the array of objects using `JSON.parse`.

And, the same `purchaseTypes` with the same `clientId` will be removed. See the demo-

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      clientId: 0,
      clients: [{
          "id": 1,
          "clientName": "Rafael Ellison"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "clientName": "Tad Beasley"
        },

      ],
      categories: [{
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type  1"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type  1"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 2"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 2"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 2,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 2"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 3"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 3"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 2,
          "purchaseType": "Purchase Type 3"
        },
        {
          "clientId": 1,
          "purchaseType": "In veritatis anim al"
        }
      ],
    }
  },

  computed: {
    filteredPurchase() {
      let categories = this.categories.filter(
        (client) => client.clientId == this.clientId
      );
      return [...new Set(categories.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)))].map(a => JSON.parse(a))
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div>
    <div>
      <label>Under Client</label>
      <select v-model="clientId">
        <option value="" selected>select clients</option>
        <option v-for="client in clients" :key="client.id" :value="client.id">{{client.clientName}}</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="purchaseCategoryId">Purchase Type</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <select multiple>
          <option value="" selected>select purchase Type</option>
          <option v-for="purchase in filteredPurchase" :key="purchase.id" :value="purchase.purchaseType">{{purchase.purchaseType}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works here but In my vue it;s not working. Basically I am getting the categories by call laravel api. when I console the categories, it shows the proxy data. How do I get the actual array?

Comment: It should not matter whether you are getting the data from API or data property. Apply this unique filtering logic just after receiving the data from the API and save the result in any data variable and use it in for loop. Let me know if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: console.log(this.unique) shows everything

Comment: what is `this.unique`? I think you are talking abot the previous answer. Please mention your problem clearly.